# Azure DevOps environment loop resource (Virtual machines)

Tags: azure-devops

I am using an Azure DevOps pipeline. I have created an Azure DevOps environment where I have 50 Virtual machines in it. Now my question is I want to loop through all the VMS in that environment and to a specific list of Virtual machines assume 10 I want to execute certain Azure DevOps tasks. One more I cannot use "tags".

Comment: please share what you have, with that said you can use Each https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#each-keyword

Comment: What's special about your specific list of Virtual machines?